# How can I outline a 3D object in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This seemed like a futile thing to look up but every single guide I check seems to work for a different use case. My question is this: given a "prism" (or just an extruded rectangle), how can I outline it with a thin black line? Below, I attempt to apply a stroke but it just changes the entire outer 3D edges.
[image]
[image]

What I actually want is this (made in PowerPoint):

[image]

How can I do this in illustrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options...

#### Option 1

You need to use the **classic 3D effect**, the new 3D architecture in recent versions of AI all result in pixel-based artwork.

- Choose `Object > Group` from the menu (even if it's only 1 object)
- Add a **New Stroke** in the **Appearance Panel** at the *Group* level. Just be certain the stroke is above the `<Contents>` listed in the panel.

[image]

#### Option 2

Use `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu — but the 3D effect will no longer be "live" and editable after doing so. You can then select individual pieces and alter their appearance as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately, the first option doesn't seem to do anything at all. If I make the group stroke 1 pt or 100 pt the object appears the same. For option 2, how exactly do I select individual pieces? No matter how much I click around with either selection tool nothing happens. Thanks again.

Comment: The first option should work without issue. Check the stack order of things in the Appearance Panel. You have to create the group, add a new stroke, make certain the stroke is above "contents" and it should work fine. And if you are "clicking around and nothing happens" there's something else taking place. Just a guess.. but try tapping the ESC key.. then try clicking.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing but it's just not working either way. Here are gifs of my two attempts, hopefully you see something I don't:
Option one: https://ibb.co/6Rfxt2h
Option two: https://ibb.co/sCQthbX

Comment: Okay.. first option may be a bug, but it may also be due to the CMYK color mode. Try it in an RGB document. I do notice some oddities here in CMYK (which I've never noticed before). Second option.. looks like it's expanding to a raster <image>. Not sure why, that may be due to the new 3D architecture.

Comment: To be honest, based upon your gifs.. it *looks* like they've really messed up the 3D in the latest AI version. I'm *purposefully* a couple version back to avoid stuff like this. If you can't rely on the Appearance panel.. and can't expand without things resulting in a raster image, I'm afraid I'm a bit stumped regarding this then.

Comment: @jhschwartz you need to use the classic 3D effects the new 3d effects are all pixels.

Comment: @Scott well yeah, dont know what they were thinking. Yeah its richer 3D but totally useless for anything further. So useless.

Comment: Option 1 works fine on an old/classic 3D object. Thank you both!

Comment: What kind of stroke do you add? I’m confused.